# how to receive a string in C# JSON Webservice that uses JSON.net

Tags: json, json.net

I have a *working* webservice that uses C# to exchange JSON data with an Android Device (thank you GSON!).  The method ultimately returns a valid JSON response.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true,Description="My Description")]
public string PostBatchData(Batchdata batchdata)
{
 //  my method
return JSONstring;
}
```

I want to use JSON.net so I can do error checking, etc.    My question is: How should I cast the object (this is receiving JSON in the HTML POST)  to string so I can use JSON.net to parse the POST?  I've tried

```
public string PostBatchData(string batchdata){}
```

but this approach isn't working (probably looking for arguments in the URL).

The excerpt below is what Fiddler is catching...  (I've edited for brevity).

```
POST http://www.myurl.com/JSONHandler.asmx/PostBatchData HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 2088
Content-Type: application/json
Host: www.myurl.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
{"batchdata":{"uname":"user1... }
```

Within the method, I think I want to use something like:

```
var container = Test.DeserializeFromJson<RootObject>(jsonstring);
```

but I am asking for a hint on how to populate jsonstring from the HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Deserialize` the Batchdata object to JSON first.

```
string json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(batchdata);
```